# Different babel environment configuration

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, webpack-2

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153628/why-does-production-build-of-react-app-with-webpack-and-babel-use-wrong-develo) seems outdated.

**Current dependencies**

```
babel: ^6.5.2
babel-core: ^6.10.4
babel-loader: ^7.0.0-beta.1
webpack: ^2.3.2
webpack-dev-server: ^2.4.2
```

**npm scripts**

```
// points to specific dev configuration
"serve": NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --hot --config ./webpack/development.js
```

[**webpack config I'm using**](https://gist.github.com/daniellizik/46bfc8a787908272ca3c5a60c04490a8)

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "env": {

    "development": {
      "presets": [
        "es2015",
        "stage-0",
        "react",
        "react-hmre"
      ],
      "plugins": [
        "babel-plugin-root-import",
        "react-html-attrs",
        "transform-es2015-destructuring",
        "transform-object-rest-spread",
        "syntax-object-rest-spread"
      ]
    },

    "production": ...
    "test": ...
  }
}
```

[Babel docs](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/#env-option) say to use the above .babelrc `env` configuration, they also mention to use this specific [`presets` config](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/#usage-via-babelrc-recommended-) -- however, babel-loader is throwing this error with the above configuration:

```
Invalid:
  `{ presets: [{option: value}] }`
Valid:
  `{ presets: [['presetName', {option: value}]] }`
```

What is the correct `.babelrc` to get different environments working?

Answer (score 1):

The proper syntax for the `presets` key is a list of lists per the error message. If you corrected your code to be the following, it should work:

```json
{
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "presets": [
        "es2015",
        "stage-0",
        "react",
        "react-hmre"
      ],
      "plugins": [
        "babel-plugin-root-import",
        "react-html-attrs",
        "transform-es2015-destructuring",
        "transform-object-rest-spread",
        "syntax-object-rest-spread"
      ]
    },
    "production": ...
    "test": ...
  }
}
```